# split a list of consecutive numbers into intervals

Tags: python, numpy

Was wondering whats the most pythonic way to split two consecutive numbers in a list into

1. n equal spaced intervals so for instance mylist below outputs (based on n = 3) the below :

   mylist = [0, 30, 36]

   mylist_new = [0, 10, 20,30,32,34,36]

2. [n, 2n, n,n] spaced intervals for instance

   mylist = [0, 25, 50]

   mylistnew = [0, 5, 15, 20, 25, 30, 40,45,50]

Comment: Why cannot it be like mylist = [0, 5,10,15,20,25,30,33, 36]?

Comment: it can be i just want something a bit more flexible so in my case [n, 2n, n, n] spaced. Is there easier way to do this then just using a for loop

Comment: In my opinion, you need at least one for loop to achieve this.